# Porque esto no funciona cuando ingreso un numero flotante?

Tags: c++, scanf

No se porque esto no funciona. Cuando ingreso un numero flotante sale un bug enorme en la consola. Ayuda! Pensaria que en scanf se leen los numeros flotantes pero al almacenarse en un integer se aproximarian a enteros. Tambien lo intente usando %d en el scan f. Pero al ingresar flotantes me resultaba en un bug horrible que me cambiaba los valores de los numeros. Lo intente de muchas formas y no se como hacer que funcione.
Como hacer que acepte floats y los convierta a integer?
Tambien noto que este error ocurre porque estoy pidiendo dos inputs seguidos. Pero cuando pido un solo input todo funciona normal.

Por cierto, ya tengo una forma para que el programa funcione, y es cambiando todos los datos de input de integer a float pero igual me gustaria saber porque esto no sirve!

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

/* 
 Un programa que acepte dos numeros del usuario y diga que numeros primoes estan dentro de ese rango
 Los numeros primos solo pueden ser divisibles entre 1 y ellos mismos
 Los numeros primos son numeros naturales
*/


int inicio = 0;
int fin = 0;
    
int main(){

    
    start:
    printf("\tIngrese un numero entero de inicio: ");
    scanf("%f", &inicio);
    printf("\tIngrese un numero entero de fin: ");
    scanf("%f", &fin);
    
    if(inicio>fin){
        printf("\tInicio debe ser menor que fin \n\tVuelva a ingresar los numeros\n\n");
        goto start;
    }

    
    
    if(inicio > fin){
    printf("\tEl numero de inicio deberia ser menor que el numero de fin.\n\tVuelva a ingresar los numeros \n\n");
    goto start;
    }
    
    else{
    printf("\n\tNumeros primos del %d al %d: ",inicio,fin);
    for(int i = inicio; i<=fin; i++){
        int divisores = 0;
        for(int j=1; j<=i; j++){
            if(i%j == 0){
                divisores++;
            }
        }

        if(divisores == 2){
            printf("\n\t%d", i);
        }
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf` no sabe el tipo que le pasaste. Tu le pasas la direccion de memoria de un entero, pero le dices que es un float. Como `scanf` no sabe que la direccion de memoria que le diste es de un entero, escribe a esa direccion de memoria segun el tipo que tu le indicaste en el formato, que es un float. Y los enteros y float se representan de formas diferentes en la memoria. El cambio de el numero se debe a que estas interpretando como un entero un espacio en la memoria que se escribio como si fuera un float.

Comment: No entiendo porque lees un float si quieres un entero, pero para conseguirlo lo correcto es leerlo a una variable float, y luego castearlo a un entero. De esa forma el valor se aproximara de la forma en la que esperabas.

Answer (score -1):

este es un ejemplo de como convertir un float en un integer:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    float a = 3.9;

    std::cout << (int)a << std::endl;

    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta.

Comment: pidio saber como transformar un float a integer, y es así como se hace con un ejemplo de impresión de pantalla, si no lees lo que dice la consulta no es mi problema.

Comment: El post dice: "*Pensaría que en scanf se leen los números flotantes pero al almacenarse en un integer se aproximarían a enteros.*", "*Como hacer que acepte floats y los convierta a integer?*", etc. Esta claro cual es la confusión que tiene, y no tiene nada que ver con hacer un cast de un tipo a otro. Además de que, aunque el tag diga `C++`, es claro por el código que esta trabajando en `C`.  Quítate la viga del ojo antes de buscar la paja en el ojo ajeno.